# Mysql Update Query increases server load

Tags: php, mysql

I am working in a dictionary type website, main table `all_english_words` contains 9 Million records. In this table `id` primary key and `word` column is unique key. In word view page I fetch the record by word and put one update query to increase view count +1 using Where ID condition. Now the problem is Website is hosted in dedicated linux server and avg server load is always `2.5 to 3` but If I remove the update query server load drops to `0.5 to 0.8`. 
What will be the problem? Is there anything mistake in my update query or how to optimize it or is there any alternative methods? 
My update query is below

```
UPDATE all_english_words SET viewcount=viewcount+1 WHERE id=8878151
```

Comment: are u write your query inside any loop ??

Comment: No. It was running only once, I'm sure about that

Comment: Remove unnecessary indexes and you an create a procedure of above query.

Comment: I am using only one index on that table. Is there any other idea?